# How to play the alarm after 5 second when the eyes had closed in python?

Tags: python, time, opencv

I writed a code for driver safety, but I don`t know how to play the alarm after 5 seconds when the eye closed or they are looking left or right.
These are the conditions whereI need to put em :

```
        if EAR < 0.26:
        cv2.putText(frame, "Alert!", (20, 100),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3, (0, 0, 255), 4)
        print("X")

        if gaze_ratio <= 1:
        cv2.putText(frame, "RIGHT", (50, 100), font, 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)
        new_frame[:] = (0, 0, 255)
    elif 1 < gaze_ratio < 1.7:
        cv2.putText(frame, "CENTER", (50, 100), font, 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)
    else:
        new_frame[:] = (255, 0, 0)
        cv2.putText(frame, "LEFT", (50, 100), font, 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment:
Please note that your indentation in your question is definitely wrong.
You might want to fix it and indicate clearly at which place you'd like to trigger the alarm within the next 5 seconds.

More context about your app, your main loop your way of playing audio might be required to give the correct answer.

However without context I give a first shot:

At the head of the file

```
import threading


def play_sound():
    # add here the  actual code playing the sound
```

at the place where you want to start of the alert

```
if shall_alert_in_5_seconds:  # replace with the appropriate if statement
    timer = threading.Timer(5, play_sound)
    timer.start()
```

Another slightly more complicated solution, that you might try:
but it all depends on what you use exactly to play some sound.

This uses one global timer and a threading Lock for avoiding concurrency issues

As long as one timer is triggered it will not trigger another one.
and there's also a function, that

At the head of the file

```
import threading

from threading import Lock


timer = None  # use only one global timer
lock = Lock()

def play_sound():
    print("start playing sound")  # comment/remove after debugging
    # add here the  actual code playing the sound
    print("end playing sound")  # comment/remove after debugging
    with lock:
        if timer is not None:
        timer = None
    print("timer cleared")  # comment/remove after debugging

    


def trigger_timer():
    print("shall trigger timer?")  # comment/remove after debugging
    with lock:
       if timer is None:
           timer = threading.Timer(5, play_sound)
           timer.start()
           print("shaltimer triggered?")  # comment/remove after debugging

def cancel_timer():
    print("shall cancel timer?")  # comment/remove after debugging
    with lock:
       if timer is not None:
           timer.cancel()
           timer = None
           print("timer canceled")  # comment/remove after debugging
```

Now at every place where you want to start sound in 5 seconds call:
`trigger_timer()`

whenever you detect an event, that tells you you don't want to play the sound anymore you call.
`cancel_timer()`

Comment: My program looks like https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MSKzfh-ubbOIvedmkpVXaewwAmnMqXuZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: did you try my suggestion?
I quickly glanced at your code and it is a simple main program with an opencv loop, so I guess my above code should work

Comment: it would be great if you fix the indentation in your question.
It makes it easier to read and understand what you try to achieve.

It would be also great if you just make the place explicitly where you'd like to trigger the alert within the next 5 seconds. e.g. `# ### here I'd like to start an alert in exactly 5 seconds`

Comment: It works sir, thank you so much, but It won`t stoped after I open the eyes, I dont find a solution.

Comment: Please look at my second enhanced solutiojn.

it is more complicated as it uses a Lock to be sure, that the variable timer is not modified after the playing of the sound while you're trying to read / modify it in the main loop.

Further I added code, that allows you to cancel the scheduled playing of the saund if an event occurs that tells you you don't have to play the sound anymore

Comment: I also added debug prints, which might help understanding the code or seeing where it fails.

Comment: I don`t know why but I m getting this error: AttributeError: __enter__ at the cancel_timer section

Comment: probably the following.

please replace all `with Lock:` with `with lock:`
This should have been the instance and not the class. (I fixed my answer accordingly)

Comment: Thanks for the effort but still got an error.Anyway I tryed something last night that works, play the sound after 5 second and stop It.But I don`t know why the alarm sound like echo or It`s lagging and after some seconds It`s blocking.Here It s the code with what I added to the new method: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DZWgJn_VkuK3l8D3NFnvEHjLfYKE2sz-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please always post the exact error.
Ideally even all lines of the error message if not you make it very difficult for others to help you.


At any time you can edit your question and add for example at the end of your initial question your most recent code, that works so far


If this answer helped, then please upvote or mark it as correct answer.

Concerning the echo and blocking issue.
I think this question merits to be posted in a new question.

Try to create the minimal code, that can show the issue and post it in a new question and post the link to it here

Comment: Thank you for the answer sir, may I have your email adress or something else where we can speak easily  ?

Comment: What I can suggest, is that whenever you have a new question you just post the link here and if my schedule allows me I can look at it

Comment: please also don't forget to mark a question as correct answer if it answered what you asked and/or to upvote any answer that gave you helpful information